# Typescript : Getting the id element from HTML returning erratic result

Tags: html, typescript

I want to get the id of a div element. The result obtained is not consistent, sometimes it get the id correctly, then it doesn't get it correctly. I want to check the result of the id obtained and see if it matches 2 strings.

**HTML**

```
 <dl class="slidedeck">
              <div class="container">
                  <img src="../assets/images/pathologiessmall.jpeg" class="img" >
                  <div id ="specialites" class="overlay" (click)="setFormVisibility($event)">
                      <div class="text" >Par spécialité</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>           
          </dl>
          <dl class="slidedeck">
              <div class="container">

                  <img src="../assets/images/pathologiessmall.jpeg" class="img" >
                  <div id ="principesactifs" class="overlay" (click)="setFormVisibility($event)">
                      <div class="text" >Par spécialité</div>
                    </div>
                  </div>           
          </dl>
```

**TypeScript**

```
public setFormVisibility(event:any){
      var target = event.target || event.srcElement || event.currentTarget;
      var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
      this.showSpecialites = (idAttr ==="specialites") ? true : false;
      this.showPrincipesActifs = (idAttr ==="principesactifs") ? true : false;
      console.log(idAttr);
      console.log("Specialite",this.showSpecialites);
      console.log("PrincipesActifs",this.showPrincipesActifs);
    }
```

Also, I'm getting false all the time despite the idAttr having one of the 2 values.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you try to print the event.target, you'll get the following output, which is stored in the first event.target object.

```
<div _ngcontent-c24="" class="text">Par spécialité</div>
```

Value of the event.target is not null so idAttr is initialized with this value. The object doesn't have the **attributes.id** attribute, so it becomes null.
Then you try to compare string with null and that's why the result of the comparison always returns false.
You can retrieve value of the id attribute it this way:

```
const idAttr = event.currentTarget.id;
```

You also can get rid of those explicitly returned true/false values, since string comparison gives you boolean value. E.g. idAttr ==="principesactifs" returns true or false.
Event if the idAttr value will be null or undefined, Javascript will implicitly convert that value to common so in result you'll also get false.
In result your method can looks like this:

```
public setFormVisibility(event:any){
  var idAttr = target.attributes.id;
  this.showSpecialites = (idAttr ==="specialites");
  this.showPrincipesActifs = (idAttr ==="principesactifs");
  console.log(idAttr);
  console.log("Specialite",this.showSpecialites);
  console.log("PrincipesActifs",this.showPrincipesActifs);
}
```

Comment: Great, thanks, it works. Issue was with the eventtarget.